# Convert a File into base64 file with angular2

Tags: angular, file, get, base64

I want to make use of Angular2 and consume a webservice that will get files via base64 string.

Tried so many things after (successfully) got the file data via http.
But I don't get it into base64, it is very frustrating... would be so nice if anyone would have a useful hint for me!

```
[import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DemoService} from './demo.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-app',
  template:`
  <h1>Get IP Address online</h1> <br>
  text2 bac  {{orderString}}<br>
  <b>json</b>: {{data}} <br>
  <b>json</b>: {{data2}} <br>
  <b>json</b>: {{data3}} <br>
  `
})


export class AppComponent {

  public order: any;
  public orderString:string;
  public lastname : string;
  public data: any;
  public data2: any;
  public data3: any;


  constructor(private http:Http) {
    console.log('constructor');
    this.orderString = 'TEST';


    var reader: FileReader;

    this.http.get('test.png')
        .subscribe(res => {
          var x: any;
          //this.data = res.blob();
          this.data2 = res.text();
          //this.data3 = btoa(res.arrayBuffer.toString());
          var fileString: string;

          reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onloadend = function() { 
             fileString = reader.result;             
             alert(fileString);
          }
          reader.onload = function() { 
             fileString = reader.result;             
             alert(fileString);
          }

          reader.readAsDataURL(res.blob());
          reader.readAsBinaryString(res.blob());

          this.data3 = fileString;
        });

        //new base64encodeexample().encodeFile('kaikaito-app-icon.png');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit');
    this.orderString = 'TEST';
  }
}][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Observable, Observer } from "rxjs";
convertFileToDataURLviaFileReader(url: string) {
 Observable.create((observer: Observer) => {
  let xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function() {
   let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
   reader.onloadend = function() {
    observer.next(reader.result);
    observer.complete();
   }
   reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.send();
 });
}
```

#### Call the method like

```
convertFileToDataURLviaFileReader(`xyz.com/a.png`).subscribe(base64 => {
 console.log(base64);
});
```

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/YvQ5y/

You can wrap it inside observable or customise it regarding your files

Comment: Thanks for that snippet. Can I also do that via TypScript because it looks like JavaScript Snippet...